# Having trouble connecting my answers to my quiz questions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a quiz and using arrays to replace the question and answers portions of my webpage.

The question portion is replacing just fine, but the answers are just showing as "undefined." Can anyone help with this?

Here is my Javascript code.

(When I refresh my webpage, it gives me a new question but the answers all say undefined.)

[image: example of current behavior]

```
const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 5;

startQuiz = () => {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuestions =[...questions];
    console.log(availableQuestions);
    getNewQuestion();
};

getNewQuestion = () => {
    questionCounter++;
    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
    currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionIndex];
    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

    choices.forEach(choice => {
        const number = choice.dataset["number"];
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
    });
};

startQuiz();
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS as well so we can replicate your issue.

Comment: How do I post those? This site is only allowing me a certain amount of code at a time.

Comment: Don't post all your code (there are max limits on the amount you can post), but post the portions of the HTML and CSS that your JavaScript references. Just hit the edit link below your question to do this.

Comment: What is the value of the `choices` array ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue relates to how choices are queried or attributed

```
choices.forEach(choice => {
     const number = choice.dataset["number"];
     choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
});
```

Give your choices a shared class, and make sure the data attribute is as below

```
<div class="choice" data-number=1></div>
<div class="choice" data-number=2></div>
<div class="choice" data-number=3></div>
<div class="choice" data-number=4></div>
```

then query your choices with querySelectorAll, and make sure to include the '.'

```
const choices = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");
```

```js
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const choices = document.querySelectorAll(".choice");

const questions = [{
    question: "Question A",
    choice1: "Choice A1",
    choice2: "Choice A2",
    choice3: "Choice A3",
    choice4: "Choice A4"
  },
  {
    question: "Question B",
    choice1: "Choice B1",
    choice2: "Choice B2",
    choice3: "Choice B3",
    choice4: "Choice B4"
  },
  {
    question: "Question C",
    choice1: "Choice C1",
    choice2: "Choice C2",
    choice3: "Choice C3",
    choice4: "Choice C4"
  },
  {
    question: "Question D",
    choice1: "Choice D1",
    choice2: "Choice D2",
    choice3: "Choice D3",
    choice4: "Choice D4"
  }
];

let questionCounter;
let score;
let currentqQuestion;
let availableQuestions;

const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 5;

const startQuiz = () => {
  questionCounter = 0;
  score = 0;
  availableQuestions = [...questions];
  getNewQuestion();
};

const getNewQuestion = () => {
  questionCounter++;
  const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
  currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionIndex];
  question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;
  choices.forEach(choice => {
    const number = choice.dataset["number"];
    choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
  });
};

startQuiz();
```

```html
<div id="question"> </div>
<div class="choice" data-number=1></div>
<div class="choice" data-number=2></div>
<div class="choice" data-number=3></div>
<div class="choice" data-number=4></div>
<button onclick="startQuiz()">Random</button>
```